# Propensity score matching on stata

Tags: stata

I have a group of treated firms in a country, and for each firm I would like to find the closest match in terms of industry, size and profitability in the rest of the country. I am working on Stata. All I need is to form a control group- could anybody guide me with the code? That'd be greatly appreciated! I currently have the following, which doesn't get me what I need:

psmatch2 (logpension) (treated sector logassets logebitda), logit ate

Comment: This is hard since you don't have a distance metric on this data. If you have two untreated firms, one is closer on size and one is closer on profitability, how do you choose which one to use? Matching firms based on probability of treatment, which is a function of size and etc., would be much easier since it is one dimensional. Also, do you want matching with or without replacement? Other user-written matching commands in Stata to consider `pscore`, `match`, and `cem` as well as Stata's own `teffects psmatch`. I would look at `cem ` first.

Comment: There's also `mahapick` based on Mahalanobis scoring.

Comment: Dmitriy thanks a lot for your response. Let's suppose I only want to match on size - which command would you recommend? ive been checking the helpfiles and notation is a bit confusing. thanks again!!

Comment: i would like to match with replacement!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you might match on x1 and x2 using Mahalanobis distance as a metric, to get the effect on y from treatment t:

```
use http://ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/files/psm, clear
psmatch2 t, mahalanobis(x1 x2) outcome(y) ate
```

The variable _n1 stores the observation number of the matched control observation for every treatment observation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitriy that's very helpful!

Comment: @İremErten If this solved your problem, you can select this as the answer.

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old post. I am trying to learn PSM technique but I am unable to access the public dataset available at the link above. Could you please provide access to the example dataset if possible? Thank you.

Comment: @PGupta It is working for me and it's not clear what the problem on your end is. You can try downloading the data manually by adding ".dta" at the end of the URL, like [this](http://ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/files/psm.dta). If that does not work, it is probably best to start another question with more details about what is not working rather than hashing it out in the comments.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error if I copy paste the link into the Google search box, and if I download with the .dta extension, I get the r(610) error ("not stata format")  while opening the file in Stata. I will try start another post although I don't think this is another "question" but simply a matter of a broken link.

Comment: What version of Stata do you have?

Comment: I'm using Stata 12

Comment: The link is not broken since you and I can both download the file. The issue is that this dataset is Stata version 14 and up (see `help dtaversion`), so your Stata 12 does not not what to do with it. There some solutions that you can find by googling, but off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to open the file with the `use13` command.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a full set of code you can run to find your average treatment effect on the treated (your most important indicator result) and to check if the data is balanced (whether your result is valid).  Before you run it, you need to make sure your treated is labeled in the following manner: 0 should be labeled as the control group and 1 should be labeled as the experimental/treatment. "neighbor(1)" means I chose the option nearest-neighbor matching. It basically pairs each treated observation with a control observation whose propensity score is closest in absolute value.

> psmatch2 treated sector logassets logebitda, outcome (logpension) neighbor(1) common

After running psmatch, you need to make sure your data is balanced. So you need to run this:

> pstest sector logassets logebitda, treated(treated)

if your t-test shows any significance below 0.05, it means your data is not balanced. to check the balance of your data visually, you can also run

> psgraph

right after your psmatch2 command.

Good luck!